# How do I continue iterating without having to wait output to finish?

Tags: python, sqlite

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('output.db')

count = 0
items = []
for item in InfStream: # assume I have an infinite stream
    items.append((item,))
    count += 1
    if count == 10000:
        conn.executemany("INSERT INTO table VALUES (?)", items)
        conn.commit()
        items = []
```

In this Python code, I have a stream of unknown length called InfStream from an API and I would like to insert the item in the stream to a table in a sqlite database. In this case, I firstly create a list of 10,000 items and then insert into the db using executemany. This will take around 1 hour. However, the code has a problem, when executemany is running, I have to wait around 15 seconds to finish. This is not acceptable in my case because, I need to keep getting the item from the stream, or otherwise it will be disconnected if I delay too long.

I would like the loop continues while executemany is running at the same time. Is it possible to do so?

nb. Input is far slower than the write. 10,000 items from input will take around 1 hour and output is only 15 seconds.

Comment: If it was infinite, attempting to stick it into a DB is a foolhardy task: you'll run out of disk space. Roughly how large is it? (Can I buffer it to disk or memory?) Is your DB node I/O saturated? (_why_ is `executemany` blocking?)

Comment: I understand an infinite stream as a stream of data with unknown length. I can either just terminate it at some time or keep it running. What do you mean with I/O saturated?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed that it's `sqlite`; that simplifies things. Is your disk writing as fast as your disk can write? is your program bottle-necked on disk I/O? CPU? network? It matters greatly: if CPU is the issue, multiprocess may very well help. If disk is the issue, probably not so much.

Comment: How do I know that? Is there any tool I can use to measure that?

Comment: Yes; it depends heavily on your operating system, however.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and Python 3.4.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a classic [Producer–consumer problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) that can best be handled using [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html).

The Producer in this case is  your InfStream, and the consumer is everything within your for block.

It would be straight forward to convert your sequential code to a multi-threaded Producer-Consumer Model and using Queue for dispatching data between the threads

Consider your Code

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('output.db')

count = 0
items = []
for item in InfStream: # assume I have an infinite stream
    items.append((item,))
    count += 1
    if count == 10000:
        conn.executemany("INSERT INTO table VALUES (?)", items)
        conn.commit()
        items = []
```

Create a **Consumer function**, to consume the data

```
def consumer(q):
    def helper():
        while True:
            items = [(q.get(),) for _ in range(10000)]
            conn.executemany("INSERT INTO table VALUES (?)", items)
            conn.commit()
    return helper
```

And a **Producer Function** to produce it until infinitum

```
def producer():
    q = Queue()
    t = Thread(target=consumer(q))
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    for item in InfStream:
        q.put(item)
    q.task_done()
```

**Additional Notes in response to the comments**

1. Theoretically, the queue can scale to infinite size, limited by system resource.
2. If the consumer cannot keep pace with producer

   Span Multiple Consumer
      ache the Data in a faster IO device and flush it later to the database.
      Make the Count configurable and dynamic.

Comment: Wouldn't the queue inevitably fill up, and then the producer would by bound by the rate at which the consumer could take items from the queue? (Which according to the question appears to be too slow.) This would delay the inevitable by the amount of memory dedicated to the queue, and how long that takes to fill, sure.

Comment: @Thanatos: In reference to your concern `Wouldn't the queue inevitably fill`, I would refer you to [class Queue.Queue(maxsize=0)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue). In reference to your other concern `This would delay the inevitable by the amount of memory dedicated to the queue`, the solution is to span multiple consumer, or to cache the data in a faster IO device and later flush it onto a database. In any case, all these intricacies are beyond the scope of the answer.

Comment: Certainly, if RAM can contain the data in question, this would work. As it's worded, the question is a big vague on this. I'm presuming that disk is not keeping up (or why would the OP's code _not_ have worked?)

Comment: @Thanatos: OP is flushing the data in bulk. During this process the input queue gets stalled. Also, refer to OPs latest update `Input is far slower than the write. 10,000 items from input will take around 1 hour and output is only 15 seconds.`.

Comment: Ah, I see. You've earned my upvote then. I do wonder if the simply reducing the flush size would alleviate the OPs disconnects, though this solution would allow the two sides to work in parallel.

Comment: Excellent example of using threads, Queue and sqlite3 executemany!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `executemany` is blocked on IO, so [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#module-threading) might actually help here, so I would try that first.  In particular, create a separate thread which will simply call `executemany` on data that the first threads throws onto a shared queue. Then, the first read can keep reading, while the second thread does the `executemany`. As the other answer pointed out, this is a Producer-Consumer problem.

If that does not solve the problem, switch to [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html).

Note that if your input is flowing in more quickly than you can write in the second thread or process, then neither solution will work, because you will fill up memory faster than you can empty it. In that case, you will have to throttle the input reading rate, regardless.